# Move browser to anchor location without causing the page to refresh

Tags: jquery, html, css, anchor

I have a web page which reloads some data using a jquery post every 30 seconds, the jquery post will will retrieve the anchors in a tab form so when the jquery does the refresh the anchor is always put to the first anchor.

Let's say I have #anchor1, #anchor2 and #anchor3. If the user is viewing #anchor2 and jquery reloads, it defaults to #anchor1. Before the jquery is done I check to see which anchor the viewer is using, and then after jquery has finished I then select the anchor that they were looking at by using the code below

```
document.location.href= "#anchor2";
```

When I use the above code it obviously causes the page to refresh so it then does the initial document.ready function to retrieve the data, so therefore the timer never gets used, it just instead permanently keeps reloading the jquery, doing it every second or so instead of using the javascript timer.

How can I direct the user to the anchor that the user was looking at before the ajax reload without causing the page to refresh.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the [`document.location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#section_5) property:

```
document.location.hash = "#anchor2";
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to sort of work. At the moment, for testing I've hard coded the anchor name ``anchor2`` It seems to work the first time the function is called but when jquery reloads the data it doesn't set the anchor again it just goes to the default as if the anchor was never set

Comment: if you're performing a full `POST/GET` to the server then JavaScript you use to set the `hash` won't seem to work because the response from the server will re-render the page. if it is a partial request `AJAX`, then this should work as advertised ...

Comment: Thanks for your help I've managed to get it working, but for some reason I need to clear the hash using ``document.location.hash = ""`` before I set it with the actual value, but it seems to work OK.